# high cpu, memory, power usage until i open the task manager they return a lil bit normal

Tags: windows, malware, cpu-usage, malwarebytes

high CPU, memory, power usage until I open the task manager they return a lil bit normal. Also, when I open a game or anything they goes up to 100% then it return normal but with drops once goes up and once goes down.

I formatted my pc but same problem
I used so much things to solve this problem such as Tron Malwarebytes etc... but same problem

please I need help I'm so exhausted

I hope anyone help me as soon as possible, thanks

Comment: Wait 10 minutes. Is there an issue or are you just observing task manager's normal behavior?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are observing, exactly. Please describe in as much detail as possible, without conjecture, just facts.

Comment: How are aware of high memory/cpu/power usage without task manager running ? Also, it is normal for CPU usage to spike when opening a game or program. You can even see CPU usage spike to 100% when opening task manager ! Please try and provide some more information on your problem.